# Come VS Come over

Tags: prepositions, difference

Please explain the difference between the following two sentences. Please try to explain it simple words.

A) Please come over this afternoon.

B) Please come this afternoon.

Answer (score 2):

The *optional* preposition in ***come over, come round*** (more dialectally, ***come by***) has no real significance in most contexts. It's really just a stylistic choice.

To the extent that there *can be* a slight shift in emphasis, *come **over*** more strongly alludes to the fact of *travelling some **distance*** in order to go to some ***location*** (as opposed to ***attending some event***; being somewhere *at a particular **time***).

That same focus on ***going*** to a place rather than ***being*** at an event also applies with *come **round*** - arguably with a slight implication that the distance to be traveled is relatively short.

The (more dialectal?) form *Please come **by** this afternoon* also implies a relatively short distance to be traveled (*and* a short visit). But to *my* ear, it often carries the additional implication that the addressee *is already traveling* in the general area - in such contexts, ***to come / drop / call by*** often implies *making a small detour* in order to make a (brief) visit.

Comment: I think that come round, come by and come over all imply something like "to my house or to my place" and most English speakers would never just use come in their stead.

Comment: I disagree. Most English speakers in most contexts would simply restrict themselves to the standard preposition ***to*** in between ***come*** and *[speaker's current location]*. But in this context it's probably worth pointing out that (dialectal?) *come **by** [my house]* doesn't work at all well if ***to*** is retained, but that "base" preposition *is* normally retained after *come **round / over / back / down / up / ..***

Comment: Furthermore, having watching just about every single British show available in my viewing area (from Downton Abbey to all the police procedurals), I have never ever heard: Come to my house for [some form of food or drink]. I have heard: Why don't you come round later for a drink? I haven't been to the UK in 20 years, but the last time I stayed with a friend, her mother was always having people round for tea, dinner or what have you.

Comment: Please don't call me obtuse. Check out relative prevalence of [*come **to** my house, come **over** my house, come **over to** my house*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=come+to+my+house%2Ccome+over+my+house%2Ccome+over+to+my+house&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccome%20to%20my%20house%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccome%20over%20my%20house%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccome%20over%20to%20my%20house%3B%2Cc0), which reflects the point I'm making here.

Comment: So downvote it. But quit with the gratuitous insults.

Comment: I removed what I said and anyway, I don't think it is an insult and I still find this answer misleading.